# glReadPixles returns 0 on device but works on simulator - iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, ios-simulator, ios9

I use `glReadPixels` to get color of selected pixel:

```
GLubyte pixels[4]= {0,0,0,0};

glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
```

and on simulator this works fine. But on real iPad `glReadPixels` returns zeroes instead first and second component.

For example, on simulator this code returns 191, 147, 222, 61 as `RGBA` (although it looks like it actually returns `GBRA` instead of `RGBA`), while on device it returns 0, 0, 64, 199 for the same color. Looks like third component is alpha and fourth is green instead of blue and alpha correspondingly.

How can I get correct values on device too?
Great thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to `glFlush()` before reading the pixels. 
Perhaps you are already. Some more context might be helpful, for e.g. what type of framebuffer are you reading from? Is it attached to a floating point texture? Are you reading from the screen buffer without double-buffering? ...

Comment: I solve the problem. The reason was that models were drawn in different colours on simulator and device. There were real colors of them. Some models were even drawn using only alpha channel, so `glReadPixels` returns 0, 0, 0, 73 for them or something similar. I don't know why this happens, but the colors are different on simulator and device. Thanks for your answer.